# reducing code.. to function

Tags: java, function, hex

```
public final byte[] getParam(String commandName,String memLocation,String dataId){
    byte[] result = new byte[9];
    result[0] = START_FRAME.getBytes()[0];
    result[1] = START_FRAME.getBytes()[0];
    result[2] = Integer.toHexString(commandMap.get(commandName)).getBytes()[0];
    result[3] = Integer.toHexString(dataIdMap.get(dataId)).getBytes()[0]; 
    result[4] = Integer.toHexString(locationMap.get(memLocation)).getBytes()[0];

    result[5] = Integer.toHexString(commandMap.get(commandName) + dataIdMap.get(dataId) + locationMap.get(memLocation)).getBytes()[0];

    result[6] = END_FRAME.getBytes()[0];
    result[7] = END_FRAME.getBytes()[0];
    result[8] = END_OF_LINE.getBytes()[0];
    //Check sum -> {{d10d}}
    return result;
}
```

how can i reduce the result[5] addition of values to a function call...

can i pass like this ?

```
    public static final byte[] createCheckSum(byte[] paramsToBeAdded){
            byte[] result = paramsToBeAdded;
            ............
            ........... etc
    return result[0] + result[2];
}
```

Correct answer:

```
private String createCheckSum(byte[] byteHolder,int startIndex,int endIndex){
     byte[] byteToCompute = byteHolder;      
     int sum = 0;     
 for(int i=startIndex; i<=endIndex; i++){    
      sum += Integer.valueOf(byteToCompute[i]);     
 }    
 return Integer.toHexString(sum);     
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want a function just for that addition? Usually function would be more advised for generic functionalities. It would be more useful to you if, lets say, you have repetitive code which you want to put away in a function.

Comment: hmmm... i can live without it... but i will have such addition throughout the project.. yea..guess you are right...

Comment: Ahhh, this was a test. I've corrected (formatted) your correct answer. But, honestly, I don't see that your correct answer matches your correct question... Initially you asked for a suggestion for method to assign something to `result[5]`. Your correct answer doesn't even use the variables from your code fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your using some class member variables. In that case, a function would make the code a bit more readable (choose a good name that shows what the method is doing):

```
private String computeSomething(String commandName,String memLocation,String dataId) {
  int  commandValue = commandMap.get(commandName);
  int  dataValue    = dataIdMap.get(dataId);
  byte memValue     = locationMap.get(memLocation)).getBytes()[0];
  return Integer.toHexString(commandValue + dataValue + memValue);
}
```

call it like this:

```
result[5] = computeSomething(commandName, memLocation, dataId);
```

(and replace the name `computeSomething` for the *readabilty effect*)

Comment: private String createCheckSum(byte[] byteHolder,int startIndex,int endIndex){
 byte[] byteToCompute = byteHolder;
 int sum = 0;
 for(int i=startIndex; i<=endIndex; i++){
  sum += Integer.valueOf(byteToCompute[i]);
 }
return Integer.toHexString(sum);
}